# Implementing endless scroll with web listview

Tags: kendo-ui

I am aware that the web version of listview doesn't have an out of the box endless scroll feature like the mobile one does. I still need to implement this in my solution and I'm not really sure where to start. All the ides I have would require me to reaload all the data again. So lets say I have 25 rows loaded. You reach the scroll point and it loads 25 more, the way I would implement it it would reload the first 25 and add 25 more. This would of course get slow the more down you go so it's not an option Ha anybody done something like this successfully? Are there any good open source endless scroll solutions available? Any tips / info / code would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 I would like to see this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually came up with a solution for this. Virtual scrolling with a grid was not what I was looking for. I ditched listview and used a datasource and plain kendo template rendering.

Here is how it works... I have a parent div for my data. I attach an event to my datasource change event and once a new page of data is read the parent div gets a child div appended inside which the new page of  data is rendered. This works flawlessly for me so far.

so my DOM looks something like this.

```
<div id="EndlesslyScrollabledata" >
    <div id="DataPage1">
       .....
   </div>
    <div id="DataPage2">
       .....
   </div>
</div>
<button> Load more data </button>
```

Each click on the load more data would move the datasource to the next page, append the next "DataPage" and render the template with the data inside the appended "DataPage".

Comment: It would be wise and prudent to showcase your code in full so we can see how was it done as we would also share the same solution to you if you wouldn't come to it on your own :)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in kendo grid in web (see virtual scrolling examples in kendo website). How about using grid with virtual scrolling and modifying display template to look like listview ?

Sample code for virtual scrolling grid is :

```
 $("#yourList").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",                
            pageSize: 25,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    cache: false,
                    url: "controller/actionmethod",
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        },

        height: 150,
        width: 50,
        pageable: true,
        //selectable: "multiple",
        scrollable: {
            virtual: true
        },

        columns: [ { field: "col1", title: "col1" }]

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come to a solution that uses the dataBinging event to emulate this behaviour:

MVC Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<your.custom.Class>()
    .Name("searchResults")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("tptSearchResult")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("Search", "ControllerName").Data("searchResults_AdditionalData");
        });


    })
)
```

You should use "AdditionalData" method if you want to send search parameters or something extra to the search service.

Javascript Code:

```
function Search(page) {
    currentPage = page;
    if(page == 1) {
        searchResults = [];
    }

    $("#searchResults").data("kendoListView").dataSource.read();
}

function searchResults_AdditionalData(ev) {
    return {
        code: $("#txtSearchCode").val(),
        pageNumber: currentPage,
        pageSize: pageSize
    };
}

var currentPage = 1;
var pageSize = 20;
var searchResults = [];
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#searchResults").data("kendoListView").bind("dataBinding", function(ev) {

        if(searchResults.length != (currentPage * pageSize)) {
            if(!!ev && !!ev.items && ev.items.length == pageSize) {
                $("#btnLoadMoreData").show();
            } else {
                $("#btnLoadMoreData").hide();
            }

            searchResults = $.merge(searchResults, ev.items);
            this.dataSource.data(searchResults);
            this.dataSource.sync();
        }

    });
});
```

Only one thing remaining: scroll to the first added element in the list after syncing.